# Adding space between cells in Matlab imagesc output

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, matlab-figure

I am creating a 2D plot in Matlab by calling this command: `imagesc(vector1, vector2, mat_weights)`. Then, I run the `colorbar` command.

I now have a smooth 2D plot, but I want to **add space between the cells**. Here's how I want it to look:

[image: Here's how the spacing should look]

How do I add such spacing between the cells/boxes?

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. take a look at `cellplot`, it won't be straight forward, but it should work.

Comment: @natan Thanks for your help - I'll take a look. If you have any experience with using cellplot, I'd appreciate if you could post some relevant sample code!

Comment: on the other hand, `pcolor` might also work... If nobody will give yuo an answer today, I'll try to solve this for you later.

Comment: @natan please see the answer using scatter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add spaces between patches of color using another function than `imagesc`. Here, `scatter` provides a straightforward solution when used with option 'filled' and marker 'square'.

Note that you need to transform your 2-D matrix into a vector, but you don't have to scale your data: scatter takes the min and max values from your data and assign them to the min and max colors of the colormap.

The code

```
% 2-D in 1-D:
Z = diag(1:10); %example of 2-D matrix to be plotted
C = reshape(Z,1,[]); %1-D transform for vector color

% input definition
sz_matrix = 10;
X = repmat( (1:sz_matrix), 1, sz_matrix);
Y = kron(1:sz_matrix,ones(1,sz_matrix));
S = 1000;                  % size of marker (handle spaces between patches)
%C = (X.^2 + Y.^2);        % second color scheme

%plot      
figure('Color', 'w', 'position', [10 10 600 400]);  
scatter(X, Y, S, C, 'fill', 's');  
set(gca, 'XLim', [0 11], 'YLim', [0 11]);  
axis square;  
colormap summer  
colorbar
```

will give

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is a piece of code for a rectangular matrix. Please note the inversion of the Y axis direction so that the graphical representation matches `disp(Z)`. To have similar (x,y) proportion in the white area separating color patches, one may try to resize manually the figure.

```
Z = diag(1:10); %example of 2-D matrix to be plotted
Z = Z(1:end-2,:); %trim for rectangular

% input definition
X = repmat(1:size(Z,2), 1, size(Z,1));
Y = kron(1:size(Z,1),ones(1,size(Z,2)));
C = reshape(Z',1,[]); %1-D transform for vector color
S = 1000;                  % size of marker (handle spaces between patches)

%plot      
figure('Color', 'w');  
scatter(X, Y, S, C, 'fill', 's'); 

set(gca, 'XLim', [0 size(Z,2)+1], 'YLim', [0 size(Z,1)+1]);  
colormap jet  
colorbar
set(gca, 'YDir','reverse');
```

The ouput:

[image]

Comment: @Magla: quick question! This code seems to break down once I supply a non-square matrix (with appropriate vector lengths for the axes, naturally). How should this be adapted? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Maxim Zaslavsky Please see the edited version that handles non-square matrices. Lot can be done to make the code more general - white area proportion or patch size corresponding to the matrix size for example.

Comment: @Magla: Thank you so much! I don't need it for this project, but if you have a chance, I'd appreciate it if you could point me to some resources or code about getting more customization into this code, like those other two examples you mentioned. Not critical though, but thanks anyway!